# What's a good way to store simple data that's used by a Command Line?

Tags: c, xml, xcode, command-line

I'm new to both Mac and the C programming language; but, I recently installed Xcode, and I've been trying to figure somethings out..

Currently I want to work on making a small Command Line game. But I need to find a good way to store simple data, like strings and integers..

So, is there a way to store information in an XML file through C? If so, would that be a good way to go about things? If not, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

For simple data you can use `NSUserDefaults`.

Example where 32 is the:

```
int score = 32.
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:score forKey:@"CurrentScore"];
```

later:

```
score = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"CurrentScore"];
```

See the documentation for NSUserDefaults, it can handle many types of data.